# How to transfer data to the target table from multiple sources without using Joiner Transformation in informatica?

Tags: informatica

I have two sources (source A and Source B), source B is an another one target table in my db. both are in diff user id . Now i have to transfer some data,s from these two sources to target table. Can i transfer data without using the joiner transfermation? how to do ?

Answer (score 2):

Using Source Qualifier -->double click Source Qualifier -->go to properties --> we have to write SQL Query (but our tables must available in same Database)

Answer (score 1):

You could join the two tables using sql in the source qualifier as long as both tables exist in the same database and the connection used can access both tables.

Answer (score 1):

try using SQL query over ride in Source Qualifier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple source definitions which go to a single Source Qualifier.
Delete the Source Qualifiers that auto-generate, and create a new Source Qualifier Transformation. Import each Source Definition you need, and tie each of the needed fields from the various source definitions to that **one** source qualifier. Writing a lot of SQL overrides defeats the purpose of using Informatica for most ETL and slows down the process. (Notice.. I did not say "never" do it..but I am currently re-developing transformations written with large SQL overrides that are very slow and use a lot of resources.)

Answer (score 0):

- First drag and drop both the source tables.
- Then delete one source qualifier and create one customized source qualifier.
- Now override the source qualifier's query using joins and load to target table.